# Change personal name associated with email address

Tags: gmail, google-account, google, google-apps, google-plus

In the Gmail app our with any other Google app, how do I change the user name associated with one of my email addresses / Google accounts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit your Google Account information](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en):

1. Sign in to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/intro). In the "Personal info & privacy" section,
2. select Your personal info.
3. Choose the information you want to edit and follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: Sorry I've already tried this but changing the account setting on the web doesn't change the user name in gmail even if I close the gmail app and open it back up. Is it a cache problem? Will this get fixed as time goes by our something? Thanks.

Comment: Try to synchronize this account or remove it and add again.

Comment: Ok, it got updated after a few minutes, no need to remove and couldn't see an option to synchronize.